# Preserving state of collection_check_boxes after form submit validation error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, form-for

I am trying to preserve the state of `collection_check_boxes` after validation fail, my situation is:

**Association**:

`post` has_many `categories` through `post_categories`

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |post| %>
  <%= post.collection_check_boxes :category, Category.all, :id, :category_name %>
  ---some other items---
  <%= post.button :submit, 'Create Post' %>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller**

```
if @post.save
  flash[:notice] = "Post was created."
  redirect_to posts_path
else
  @post = Post.new(return_post_params)
  render :new
end
```

I put all params in `return_post_params`, the format of `category` is `["1", "2", "3"]` but I don't know how to make the checkboxes to be checked after validation fail.

Any ideas are appreciated!